# How Do I Make My Quiz Site Work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I made a quiz site and I can not make it display the answers I got correct and the image associated with the correct enough answers.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/tovasfo/pen/veJdxd

```html
<head>
  <title>This quiz</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Short canadian quiz</h1>
  <h2>If you cheat it will take longer</h2>

  <form id="quiz" name="quiz">

    <p class="questions">What is our national animal?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q1" value="Bed">Bed<br>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q1" value="Beaver">Beaver<br>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q1" value="Bed">It's not this<br>

    <!-- // the answer is Beaver  -->

    <p class="questions">What is our national sport?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q2" value="Hockey">Hockey<br>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q2" value="Tag">Tag<br>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q2" value="Poutine">Poutine<br>

    <!-- // Hockey  -->

    <p class="questions">How many points are on the maple leaf on the flag?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q3" value="75">75<br>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q3" value="9">9<br>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q3" value="11">11<br>

    <!-- // 11  -->

    <p class="questions">What alcholic beverage do we consume the most?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q4" value="Wine">Wine<br>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q4" value="Beer">Beer<br>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q4" value="Red Bull">Red Bull<br>

    <!-- // Beer  -->

    <p class="questions">What is the capital of canada?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q5" value="Toronto">Toronto<br>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q5" value="Ottawa">Ottawa<br>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q5" value="Your Wrong City">Your Wrong City<br>

    <!-- // Ottawa  -->

    <p class="questions">What was invented by a canadian?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q6" value="French Fries Baby">French Fries Baby<br>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q6" value="Basketball Baby">Basketball Baby<br>
    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q6" value="I'm Sorry">I'm Sorry<br>


    <!-- // Basketball baby -->


    <p><input id="button" type="button" value="submit" onclick="check();"></p>
  </form>
  <div id="done">
    <p id="correct"></p>
    <p id="message"></p>
  </div>


</body>


</html>
```

CSS

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif, arial;
}

#done {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript

```js
function check() {
  var q1 = document.quiz.q1.value;
  var q2 = document.quiz.q2.value;
  var q3 = document.quiz.q3.value;
  var q4 = document.quiz.q4.value;
  var q5 = document.quiz.q5.value;
  var q6 = document.quiz.q6.value;
  var correct = 0;

  if (q1 == "Beaver") {
    correct++;
  }

  if (q2 == "Hockey") {
    correct++;
  }

  if (q3 == "11") {
    correct++;
  }

  if (q4 == "Beer") {
    correct++;
  }

  if (q5 == "Ottawa") {
    correct++;
  }

  if (q6 == "Basketball baby") {
    correct++;
  }

  var messages = [
    "YOU ARE UNSTOPPABLE!!!",
    "Excellent work",
    "You got most",
    "It's alright",
    "It's not good ahhhhh",
    "Don't try and act dumb",
    "Your so drunk"
  ];
  var pictures = [
    "img/socol.gif",
    "img/tenor.gif",
    "img/mity.gif",
    "img/okay.gif",
    "img/ohno.gif",
    "img/dumb.gif",
    "img/drunky.gif"
  ];
  var range;

  if (correct > 5) {
    range = 0;
  }

  if (correct > 4 && correct < 6) {
    range = 1;
  }

  if (correct > 3 && correct < 5) {
    range = 2;
  }

  if (correct > 2 && correct < 4) {
    range = 3;
  }

  if (correct > 1 && correct < 3) {
    range = 4;
  }

  if (correct > 0 && correct < 2) {
    range = 5;
  }

  if (correct < 1) {
    range = 6;
  }

  document.getElementById("done").style.visiblity = "visible";
  document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML =
    "you got " + correct + " correct.";
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[range];
  document.getElementById("picture").src = pictures[range];
}
```

This is all I have for now. I just want the quiz to actually function by giving the user how many answers he or she got right and the correct image.

Comment: you have a typo : `visiblity` instead of `visibility`

Comment: I Upvote your question and I fix your code please if I help you just upvote my answer and added ass useful

Answer (score 1):

### You must include you javascript file on the bottom of the  page try this and is gonna work

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Short canadian quiz</h1>
    <h2>If you cheat it will take longer</h2>

    <form id="quiz" name="quiz">

      <p class="questions">What is our national animal?</p>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q1" value="Bed">Bed<br>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q1" value="Beaver">Beaver<br>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q1" value="Bed">It's not this<br>

      <!-- // the answer is Beaver  -->

      <p class="questions">What is our national sport?</p>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q2" value="Hockey">Hockey<br>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q2" value="Tag">Tag<br>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q2" value="Poutine">Poutine<br>

      <!-- // Hockey  -->

      <p class="questions">How many points are on the maple leaf on the flag?</p>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q3" value="75">75<br>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q3" value="9">9<br>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q3" value="11">11<br>

      <!-- // 11  -->

      <p class="questions">What alcholic beverage do we consume the most?</p>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q4" value="Wine">Wine<br>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q4" value="Beer">Beer<br>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q4" value="Red Bull">Red Bull<br>

      <!-- // Beer  -->

      <p class="questions">What is the capital of canada?</p>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q5" value="Toronto">Toronto<br>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q5" value="Ottawa">Ottawa<br>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q5" value="Your Wrong City">Your Wrong City<br>

      <!-- // Ottawa  -->

      <p class="questions">What was invented by a canadian?</p>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q6" value="French Fries Baby">French Fries Baby<br>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q6" value="Basketball Baby">Basketball Baby<br>
      <input type="radio" id="mc" name="q6" value="I'm Sorry">I'm Sorry<br>


      <!-- // Basketball baby -->


      <p><input id="button" type="button" value="submit" onclick="check();"></p>
    </form>
    <div id="done">
      <p id="correct"></p>
      <p id="message"></p>
    </div>


    <script src="./main.js"></script>  <======= Heare
</body>
</html>
```

### main.js

```
function check() {
  var q1 = document.quiz.q1.value;
  var q2 = document.quiz.q2.value;
  var q3 = document.quiz.q3.value;
  var q4 = document.quiz.q4.value;
  var q5 = document.quiz.q5.value;
  var q6 = document.quiz.q6.value;
  var correct = 0;

  if (q1 == "Beaver") {
    correct++;
  }

  if (q2 == "Hockey") {
    correct++;
  }

  if (q3 == "11") {
    correct++;
  }

  if (q4 == "Beer") {
    correct++;
  }

  if (q5 == "Ottawa") {
    correct++;
  }

  if (q6 == "Basketball baby") {
    correct++;
  }

  var messages = [
    "YOU ARE UNSTOPPABLE!!!",
    "Excellent work",
    "You got most",
    "It's alright",
    "It's not good ahhhhh",
    "Don't try and act dumb",
    "Your so drunk"
  ];
  var pictures = [
    "img/socol.gif",
    "img/tenor.gif",
    "img/mity.gif",
    "img/okay.gif",
    "img/ohno.gif",
    "img/dumb.gif",
    "img/drunky.gif"
  ];
  var range;

  if (correct > 5) {
    range = 0;
  }

  if (correct > 4 && correct < 6) {
    range = 1;
  }

  if (correct > 3 && correct < 5) {
    range = 2;
  }

  if (correct > 2 && correct < 4) {
    range = 3;
  }

  if (correct > 1 && correct < 3) {
    range = 4;
  }

  if (correct > 0 && correct < 2) {
    range = 5;
  }

  if (correct < 1) {
    range = 6;
  }

  document.getElementById("done").style.visiblity = "visible";
  document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML =
    "you got " + correct + " correct.";
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[range];
  document.getElementById("picture").src = pictures[range];
}
```

Comment: It works but it can not display the image associated with the number of correct responses.